# SQL, update column in a specific row, instead of all rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, plpgsql

The task is to update the specific row in the column `klienta_nr`, which is located in the table `klientu_ieteikumi`. If a specific row is deleted in `klienti` table. This code updates the whole column not the specific row. What is the problem?

```
CREATE FUNCTION "funkc"() RETURNS "opaque" AS '
DECLARE
BEGIN

IF (TG_OP = ''DELETE'') THEN
UPDATE klientu_ieteikumi SET klienta_nr = NULL ; 
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER "triger"
AFTER DELETE ON "klienti"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE funkc();
```

---

This one did what I wanted, thanks anyway everyone :)

```
CREATE FUNCTION "funkcija1"() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$

BEGIN

UPDATE klientu_ieteikumi SET klienta_nr = NULL 
FROM klienti WHERE old.klienta_nr = klientu_ieteikumi.klienta_nr;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "trigeris"
AFTER DELETE ON "klienti"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE funkcija1();
```

Answer (score 2):

you need a `WHERE` clause to restrict the number of rows affected by the statement.

edit:

```
UPDATE klientu_ieteikumi 
SET klienta_nr = NULL 
WHERE klienta_ieteikumi.klienta_nr = klienti.klienta_nr
```

Comment: could WHERE klienta_ieteikumi.klienta_nr = klienti.klienta_nr; work?

Comment: with alot of guessing on my part - that looks promising.

Comment: Ok, but where should I put it?

Answer (score 0):

You presented "solution" cannot work and is **wrong in a sneaky way**.

```
CREATE FUNCTION funkcija1()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN

CREATE FUNCTION funkcija1()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN

UPDATE klientu_ieteikumi
SET    klienta_nr = NULL 
FROM   klienti  -- !!
WHERE  klientu_ieteikumi.klienta_nr = OLD.klienta_nr;

RETURN NEW;
RETURN NULL;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER trigeris
AFTER DELETE ON klienti
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE funkcija1();
```

- There is no `NEW` in an `AFTER` trigger. This wouldn't work at all and raise an exception immediately.
- The unbound (and utterly pointless) table `klienti` in the `FROM` clause leads to a `CROSS JOIN`. I.e., instead of just one time, the `UPDATE` is executed as many times as there are rows in `klienti`. This would be a major drag on performance, and **you might never find out**, since there is no error message. Just a lot of wasted cycles and table bloat on your server.